# Tool for Customer Support + Analytics

Tags: data-analysis, analytics, support-tracker

I run a customer support and user analytics team at a software startup.

We get 2000+ tickets each day.  90%+ do not need any answer, they just need for me to analyse the problem and pass the info to the tech teams to solve.  5% need some form of answer. 5% are tickets that, in order to understand the technical issue, I want to reach out to the user for more info.

Currently we user Zendesk and it's great for the 10% of the time that I want to contact a user.  But it's crappy for analysing the technical metadata that comes with each user report so I can actually solve the bugs!

Case in point: Just after releasing a new software version I get 600 tickets about problem X.  Each ticket has meta data including what device it was sent from, a stack trace, what cellular network, OS version, and so on.  Currently, I tag all of these in Zendesk, use a custom REST API tool to export them to a csv and them dump them into a pivot table in excel where I see that 500 of them are all iPhone 4 devices running iOS 6.1.5.  That info goes to my iOS development team and they now have the facts to fix the problem.

I'd like a tool that can do both.  All the CRM tools I've seen are focused only on communicating with users and all the analytics tools I've seen have no way to communicate and track a conversation with users.

I can't be the only company with this problem.  I need a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of tag creation, you should be able to get quick "insights" into the data using the Zendesk reportings tab. I apologize if you were already aware of this, but it does seem to meet the needs you described.

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203658046-Introducing-Insights-Make-your-data-mean-something

Source: Software startup with over 3 million users and we also use Zendesk.